# Where in android project does it set menu for activity

Tags: android

I just created a new project in Android Studio v2.2.3 - a project targeting API level 15 and with one blank activity to start.

The XML for that activity is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_starting"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bfsog.apps.testapp.StartingActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Lorem ipsum"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

In the preview pane and when I run this, at the top of the screen there is a blue bar with the name of my app and then below it is my textview.

I then created a new blank activity, with the same XML but slightly different text:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_display_notification"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.bfsog.apps.testapp.SecondActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ipsum lorem"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now in the preview pane for the second activity it does not have the horizontal blue bar at the top.

Where is this specified?

Edit: My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.bfsog.apps.testapp">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".StartingActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

The first activity does not specify the theme, but it gets the blue bar. The second activity specifies the theme, but it does not appear.

Comment: It's ActionBar , what do you need help with it? Trying to remove it ?

Comment: tools:context, generally species the themes needed for that activity, set the same theme for second activity in manifest and see , else on top ,there should be something like themes , check on it once

Comment: You have to define themes in style.xml .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use same theme on both the activity.Probably copy theme from first activity to another.Or Create new one like this.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

then on `ActivityManifest.xml`

```
<activity
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:name=".SecondAct" >
```

Answer (score 0):

it is called [ActionBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html)

in your res/values/styles:

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item> //this is the action bar background color
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

to change it add your custom theme;

```
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
```

to show action bar :

in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"  //this is the text showing on action bar
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity> //use theme
```

you can show custom action bar with different color:

```
android:theme="@style/MyCustomTheme"
```

to hide action bar in a activity use:

```
<activity
       android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
/>
```

Comment: Okay but as you can see from my manifest above I am specifying the theme for the second activity and still no bar

Comment: post the `secondActivity code` also make sure it extends `AppcompatActivity`